# C# UWP Disable pointer wheel

Tags: c#, uwp, gesture, scrollviewer

In C# UWP app how to disable pointer wheel on scrollviewer, and still be able to move scroll with touch?

I have situation like this:

```
<ScrollViewer 
    VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <ListView/>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This in your code behind should override your mouse wheel input if you assign a focus condition.

```
public MyView()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerWheelChanged += CoreWindow_PointerWheelChanged;
}

private void CoreWindow_PointerWheelChanged(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
{
     if (!SomeConditionLikeYourScrollViewerIsFocused)
     {
        args.Handled = true;
     }
     else { // do nothing }        
}
```

Comment: I need this just for listview, not for the whole window.

Comment: That’s what it is.  args.Handled means it isn’t going to override anything.